# PHP end() function not getting end Array item and object key in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In my Laravel project, I've got a job set up which runs and attempts to notify a user based on their threshold and chosen alert metrics. I'm using the php `end()` method to get the last item in an array and then attempting to get whatever metric the user has chosen.

However, upon dumping the data, this isn't returning the last array item, it's returning every item and I'm not sure why?

When I dump my data, I'm getting this format instead of the last item in the array:

```
[2021-04-13 13:30:45] production.DEBUG: array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'event_category' => 'My Category',
     'event_action' => 'My Event',
     'event_count' => '2190',
     'period_from' => '2021-04-13 00:00:00',
     'period_to' => '2021-04-13 13:30:02',
     'created_at' => '2021-04-13 13:30:06',
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'event_category' => 'My Category',
     'event_action' => 'My Event',
     'event_count' => '5184',
     'period_from' => '2021-04-12 00:00:00',
     'period_to' => '2021-04-12 23:57:02',
     'created_at' => '2021-04-12 23:57:07',
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'event_category' => 'My Category',
     'event_action' => 'My Event',
     'event_count' => '3820',
     'period_from' => '2021-04-11 00:00:00',
     'period_to' => '2021-04-11 23:57:02',
     'created_at' => '2021-04-11 23:57:07',
  ),
)
```

I should just be seeing the last item, amongst all of my code, the following is of significant value here:

```php
/**
 * Notify if data meets threshold & alert rules
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function notifyAlertThreshold($alerts, $data)
{
    $newestDataPart = end($data) ?? null;

    // alerts for data source
    foreach ($alerts as $key => $alert) {
      Log::debug($newestDataPart);

      $metric = !isset($newestDataPart->{$alert->metric}) ? $newestDataPart : $newestDataPart->{$alert->metric};

    }

}
```

In context, here's some mode of the code, but the primary question here, is why is my `end()` method not returning the last item?

```php
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{

  $filters = json_decode($this->report->discovery_filters, true);
  $this->reportStatus = 'complete';
  $data = [];

  foreach ($filters as $findableKey => $findable) {

    /*
    ** If there are datasets on the findable objec, then we assume
    ** that we can build up a chart or some data structure.
    */
    if (isset($findable['datasets'])) {
      $pushableDatasets = [];
      foreach ($findable['datasets'] as $datasetKey => $dataset) {

        // query data
        if (isset($dataset['query'])) {
          $chartLabel = $findable['name'] ?? 'Untitled Chart';
          $this->setDynamicChartOptions($chartLabel);

          $additionFromField = $dataset['query']['additionFromField'] ?? '';
          $resultData = [];

          if ($dataset['query']['prefersConversionCalculation'] == 'yes') {
            $totals = DB::table($dataset['query']['table'])
                        ->select($dataset['query']['columns'])
                        ->where($dataset['query']['calculateConversionFromTotals'])
                        ->orderBy($dataset['query']['orderBy']['field'], $dataset['query']['orderBy']['direction'])
                        ->get()
                        ->chunk(100);

            $goal = DB::table($dataset['query']['table'])
                      ->select($dataset['query']['columns'])
                      ->where($dataset['query']['calculateConversionByGoal'])
                      ->orderBy($dataset['query']['orderBy']['field'], $dataset['query']['orderBy']['direction'])
                      ->get()
                      ->chunk(100);

            $totals = $totals->flatten();
            $goal = $goal->flatten();

            $totalsGrouped = $this->groupData(
              $totals,
              $dataset['query']['groupBy'],
              $dataset['query']['groupByFormat'],
              $additionFromField
            );

            $goalsGrouped = $this->groupData(
              $goal,
              $dataset['query']['groupBy'],
              $dataset['query']['groupByFormat'],
              $additionFromField
            );

            $totalsGroupedFlattened = $totalsGrouped->flatten();
            $goalsGroupedFlattened = $goalsGrouped->flatten();
            $resultData = $this->getStructure($findable, $datasetKey, $goalsGroupedFlattened, $totalsGroupedFlattened);

            array_push($pushableDatasets, $resultData);

          } else {

            $res = DB::table($dataset['query']['table'])
                           ->select($dataset['query']['columns'])
                           ->where($dataset['query']['filterBy'])
                           ->orderBy($dataset['query']['orderBy']['field'], $dataset['query']['orderBy']['direction'])
                           ->get()
                           ->chunk(100);

            $res = $res->flatten();

            if (isset($dataset['query']['useGrouping']) && $dataset['query']['useGrouping'] == 'yes') {
              $results = $this->groupData(
                $res,
                $dataset['query']['groupBy'],
                $dataset['query']['groupByFormat'],
                $additionFromField
              );

              // if we're using an addition function our array is already flattened
              if (!empty($additionFromField)) {
                $resultData = $results;
              } else {
                $resultData = $results->flatten();
              }

              array_push($pushableDatasets, $this->getStructure($findable, $datasetKey, $resultData));
            }

          }


          $dataForAlerts = $resultData;
          if ($dataset['query']['prefersConversionCalculation'] == 'yes') {
            $dataForAlerts = $dataForAlerts['data'];
          }

          // alerting
          $alerts = $this->getAlertThresholds($dataset['query']['table']);
          $this->notifyAlertThreshold($alerts, $dataForAlerts);
        }

      }

      $findable['datasets'] = $pushableDatasets;
    }

    array_push($data, $findable);
  }

  // no data or it's empty
  if (!isset($data) || empty($data)) {
    $this->reportStatus = 'error';
  }

  // create our report data entry
  $this->updateReportData(false, $data);
}
```

Comment: From your array which item is the last item?

Comment: What is the structure of the array you're calling `end` on? Can you please share a dump of it?

Comment: did you check if $data is a multi-dimensional array or not?

Comment: `$data` contains the date instead of `[0]` etc when dumping the data. I'm expecting `end` to return just one whole item from the array, and the last one -> 2

Comment: Do you tried to use Laravel collection methods? For example collect($data)->last();